# In a meta-analysis, do you report the full N of each study or just the experimental n?

Tags: sample-size, meta-analysis, reporting

I just noticed that one meta-analysis (Jeon & Day, 2016) reported only the size of the experimental group. For example, when I look at the particular N sizes for the Robb & Kano (2013) studies, they report, in Table 3, the the economics majors as N = 543, which is the experimental cohort size (Robb & Kano Table 5), but this excludes the 555 students in the control cohort.

[The effectiveness of ER on reading proficiency: A meta-analysis. Reading in a Foreign Language, 28(2), 246–265](http://doi.org/10.1017/SOI42716411000932) by Jeon, E.-Y., & Day, R. R. (2016)

[Effective extensive reading outside the classroom: A large-scale experiment. Reading in a Foreign Language, 25(2), 234–247](http://nflrc.hawaii.edu/rfl/October2013/articles/robb.pdf) by Robb, T., & Kano, M. (2013)

Comment: If a study has equal sample sizes for both the experimental and the control group, I guess you could report just one of these but mention why. If a study has unequal sample sizes, reporting just the sample size for the experimental group seems incomplete to me (unless you know the ratio of the two sample sizes and can work your way back to the sample size of the control group). It's poor practice, in my view, to not report both sample sizes for reproducibility purposes in a meta-analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: They should have reported the N for both arms.

Long answer: Reporting is often a weakness of any research project. The Equator network provides suggestions on what to report based on the study design. For systematic reviews and meta-analyses in healthcare there are a few guidelines that can be followed (e.g. Methodological Expectations of Cochrane Systematic Reviews MECIR, PRISMA and its extensions, etc.).

In general, it better to report all data used in a meta-analysis at the study level for both arms rather than cherry-pick what is reported or only reporting a summary effect estimate for each study (or just the results of the meta-analysis). This provides transparency.

Hope this helps.